Anthology Horror Movie with a realtor trying to sell house
I saw this movie on TV, in 2001/2002. It's an English movie from probably the early 90s. It could be a B-movie.
In it, we see a real estate agent who is trying to sell a house to a family. But with every house there is a horror story connected. As something happened in each house, the family keeps getting the realtor show them different houses.
Also the realtor is seen talking to someone on phone and the thing is that he must sell a house that day.

Sounds like you're looking for Terror Tract.

Terror Tract is a 2000 anthology dark comedy/horror film featuring John Ritter as a real-estate agent trying to sell a variety of houses to a young couple; each with a horror story associated with it. The segment "Make Me an Offer" is the overall plot of the film with Ritter and the three segments dramatized are the different, horrifying stories behind each house. Ritter as the estate agent is desperately trying to close a deal with them to meet a sales target that afternoon, but is confounded each time by his honesty which compels him to tell the grisly stories associated with each house he shows the couple.

Bryan Cranston stars in one of the segments. Here's the trailer:



